# This expression was expected to have type 'double' but here has type 'unit'

Tags: f#

Ive an array of integers, and want to do the following operation:

```
s += array(index+1) - array(index)
```

so, I tried the below:

```
let mutable s =0
for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
s <- series.[i+1] - series.[i] + s
```

but I goy an error:

> This expression was expected to have type
>       'double'     but here has type
>       'unit'

**UPDATE**

The full code

```
let series = [|30;21;29;31;40;48;53;47;37;39;31;29;17;9;20;24;27;35;41;38;
          27;31;27;26;21;13;21;18;33;35;40;36;22;24;21;20;17;14;17;19;
          26;29;40;31;20;24;18;26;17;9;17;21;28;32;46;33;23;28;22;27;
          18;8;17;21;31;34;44;38;31;30;26;32|]

let initialTrend series slen : double=
    let mutable s = 0
    for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
    s <- series.[i+1] - series.[i] + s
```

Comment: With `let slen = 10` and `let series = [|0..10|]` I don't get this error. Can you share a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: see updated question pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are telling that the function will return a double and the error message is telling you that it doesn't return anything, that's correct.

Either, remove the return type:

```
let initialTrend series slen : unit =
  let mutable s = 0
  for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
    s <- series.[i+1] - series.[i] + s
```

or change the way the function works:

```
let initialTrend (series: _ list) slen : double=
    let mutable s = 0
    for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
        s <- series.[i+1] - series.[i] + s
    float s
```

But, looking at your recent questions, you are still sticking to mutability. I would suggest to use a higher order function here instead:

```
let initialTrend (series: float [])  : double =
    Array.pairwise series |> Array.fold (fun s (x0, x1) -> x1 - x0 + s) 0.
```

Comment: OK, I added an example, using a ``fold``.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I do not want the `pairwise` let's say I want to handle each index and the fourth element after it, is there a higher function for this!

Comment: Yes, there is ``Array.windowed`` which can serve that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, This worked fine with me `series |> Array.windowed 5
           |> Array.fold (fun s x -> 
                                (x |> Array.rev |> Array.head) -  (x |> Array.head) + s) 0
           |> float`

Comment: the 2nd suggestion on letting the function return `double`, but why then convert the `int` to `float` rather than `double`? Does that even work?

Comment: ``float`` and ``double`` are aliases for the same type. Actually, all the data should already be float, it should be the caller responsibility to transform ints to floats, but I just showed a working solution and needed to make it compile with the inputs he has.